# "Reshape" long format data into sequences of two

Tags: r, reshape

I have a data frame that lists observed behavior ("observation"), observed subjects ("code"), and the time of observation ("day" and "time"):

```
code   day   time       observation
A1     1     07:30:00   w
A1     1     12:15:00   f
A1     1     18:40:00   v
B2     1     08:12:00   q
B2     1     09:33:00   s
B2     2     14:10:00   a
B2     2     20:20:00   g
```

From this data, I want to create a new data frame in which every observation is paired with the one that follows it, within a single subject. For the sample data, the resulting new data frame should look like this:

```
code   night   obs.1   obs.2
A1     FALSE   w       f
A1     FALSE   f       v
B2     FALSE   q       s
B2     TRUE    s       a
B2     FALSE   a       g
```

The new variable "night" states whether or not there was a night between the two observations, that is, whether the second observation was made on the next day. (Please note how every observation that is not the first or last for one subject appears *twice* in the new data frame, because it is both the preceding observation in one and the following observation in another series of two observations.)

I wanted to write a loop that goes through the original data frame line by line and then looks a the next line and compares the "code" and the "day" and then creates a new line when the code is the same and sets "night" to "TRUE" when the "day" changes. Something like the code in the Sample Data below.

**Is there a better way than looping through the data?**

For example, is it possible to achieve this with something like `reshape()`?

---

*Sample Data*

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection("
code day time observation
A1 1 07:30:00 w
B2 2 14:10:00 a
A1 1 12:15:00 f
A1 1 18:40:00 v
B2 1 08:12:00 q
B2 1 09:33:00 s
B2 2 20:20:00 g
"), header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)

dat$code <- as.factor(dat$code)
dat$day <- as.factor(dat$day)
dat$time <- strptime(dat$time, "%T")

dat <- dat[with(dat, order(code, day, time)), ]  # so we can loop

dat.pairs <- data.frame(
                            code = character(),
                            night = logical(),
                            obs.1 = character(),
                            obs.2 = character(),
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
                       )

for (i in 1:(nrow(dat)-1)) {
    if (dat[i, ]$code == dat[i+1, ]$code) {
        if (dat[i, ]$day == dat[i+1, ]$day) {
            n = FALSE
        } else {
            n = TRUE
        }
        dat.pairs <- rbind(dat.pairs, data.frame(code = dat[i, ]$code, night = n, obs.1 = dat[i, ]$observation, obs.2 = dat[i+1, ]$observation))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quite straight forward option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, 
          .(
            night = diff(day) == 1,
            obs.1 = head(observation, -1),
            obs.2 = tail(observation, -1)
           ),
          by = code]

#    code night obs.1 obs.2
# 1:   A1 FALSE     w     f
# 2:   A1 FALSE     f     v
# 3:   B2 FALSE     q     s
# 4:   B2  TRUE     s     a
# 5:   B2 FALSE     a     g
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat$day<-as.numeric(as.character(dat$day)) #to turn into numeric
dat$time<-as.POSIXct(dat$time) #dplyr can't work with POSIXlt
dat%>%
  group_by(code)%>%
  rename(obs.1=observation)%>%
  mutate(obs.2=lead(obs.1),night=lead(day)>day)%>%
  filter(!is.na(obs.2))%>%
  select(code,night,obs.1,obs.2)
```

It works for the example:

```
Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
Groups: code [2]

    code night obs.1 obs.2
  <fctr> <lgl> <chr> <chr>
1     A1 FALSE     w     f
2     A1 FALSE     f     v
3     B2 FALSE     q     s
4     B2  TRUE     s     a
5     B2 FALSE     a     g
```

**edit:** took into account the comments from juod and Sotos

Answer (score 0):

**Update: I figured out how to do this with reshape so have replaced the previous partial solution**

To answer your question, yes it is possible to achieve this with reshape().  Note that, I'm referring to the stats::reshape() function.

```
dat$night <- unlist(by(dat, 
                       dat$code, 
                       FUN=function(x) c((x[2:nrow(x), 2] - x[1:(nrow(x)-1), 2])==1, FALSE)))

dat$id.1 <- unlist(by(dat, 
                      dat$code, 
                      FUN=function(x) c(rep(1:nrow(x), each=2))[1:nrow(x)]))
dat$id.2 <- unlist(by(dat, 
                      dat$code, 
                      FUN=function(x) c(0, rep(1:nrow(x), each=2))[1:nrow(x)]))
dat$visit.1 <- unlist(by(dat, 
                         dat$code, 
                         FUN=function(x) rep(c(1,2), nrow(x))[1:nrow(x)]))
dat$visit.2 <- unlist(by(dat, 
                         dat$code, 
                         FUN=function(x) c(0, rep(c(1,2), nrow(x)))[1:nrow(x)]))
dat

rows1 <- na.omit(reshape(dat, 
                         timevar = "visit.1", 
                         idvar = c("code", "id.1"), 
                         direction = "wide", 
                         v.names = "observation", 
                         drop = c("day", "visit.2")))
rows2 <- na.omit(reshape(dat[dat$visit.2 != 0,], 
                         timevar = "visit.2", 
                         idvar = c("code", "id.2"), 
                         direction = "wide", 
                         v.names = "observation", 
                         drop = c("day", "visit.1")))

dat.pairs <- rbind(rows1, rows2)
dat.pairs[order(dat.pairs$code, dat.pairs$time), c("code", "night", "observation.1", "observation.2")]
  code night observation.1 observation.2
1   A1 FALSE             w             f
3   A1 FALSE             f             v
5   B2 FALSE             q             s
6   B2  TRUE             s             a
2   B2 FALSE             a             g
```

**Here is an alternative approach using base R functions which also avoids looping through the data:**

```
dat$day <- as.numeric(as.character(dat$day))
dat$night <- unlist(by(dat, 
                       dat$code, 
                       FUN=function(x) c((x[2:nrow(x), 2] - x[1:(nrow(x)-1), 2])==1, FALSE)))

dat$obs.1 <- dat$observation
dat$obs.2 <- unlist(by(dat, 
                       dat$code, 
                       FUN=function(x) c(x[2:nrow(x), 4], NA)))

dat.pairs <- dat[!is.na(dat$obs.2), c("code", "night", "obs.1", "obs.2")]
dat.pairs$code <- as.character(dat.pairs$code)
```

This will reproduce the example results:

```
dat.pairs
  code night obs.1 obs.2
1   A1 FALSE     w     f
3   A1 FALSE     f     v
5   B2 FALSE     q     s
6   B2  TRUE     s     a
2   B2 FALSE     a     g
```